# Subnavigation on iPad or Other Tablet

Tags: navigation, tablet, responsive

I have a navigation and subnavigation bar that runs in parallel across the horizontal width of the page.  It works fine on desktop computers.  As you hover over the main navigation items, its corresponding subnavigation is shown below it.

The problem I have is on tablets, because there really isn't a hover state.  I could use icons to display the subnavigation but there really isn't enough room.  Other options include long clicks or double clicks. I'm not certain about the viability of these options.

Comment: What is the problem with using a normal onclick event instead of hover? Why do you need long click?

Comment: I agree with @rlb. This is more of a code question I believe. If you are going to make submenus available on hover on desktop you need to unbind your javascript events for devices and apply a click event only. Alternatively if you do not want to deal with the headache of reworking your scripts just use a click event to control your menus and apply a "caret" to the items which contain a sub menu. This visual clue will notify your users a submenu is present

Comment: Well, the main navigation also needs to go to a page?  Right now, if you click on main, it goes straight to the page and doesn't show the subnav.

Comment: @TheHawk main navigation doesn't necessarily have to go to a location. As long as you maintain a certain level of consistency.

Comment: For instance, look at Amazon's navigation, the top tier doesn't go anywhere, until you go in.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that for mobile devices you provide a different navigation experience than for your desktop solutions. An excellent place to start is Brad Frost's article on responsive navigation patterns:

http://bradfrost.com/blog/web/responsive-nav-patterns/

I've used both "The Toggle" and the "Fly Out" options, and they can be modified to allow for sub-navigation when you select a nav item.

Answer (score 0):

Before even getting to the subnav bar (child nav), you are already having an issue on the main nav bar (parent nav).

Let's assume that the content on a page to which a parent item links to is equal to the items in the child nav. Then it begs the question: why do you need that page? (e.g. perhaps for SEO reasons)

If the content is not equal to the child items, than you will have a UI issue as explained below.

**Issue 1**
Users can click a parent item in order to get to that page but a hover state on that same item will also show the children. Many users won't click an item in the parent nav once the child nav for that item shows up below, thinking "ah, now I have to choose an item below". Given that the content on a page (parent nav) is valuable, many users won't even get there.
As Jason pointed out a caret is a good indicator that there are more nav items hidden in that very parent, however, by experience I would say even fewer people will notice that they could have even clicked the parent itself.

**Issue 2** 
Imagine for a second that a user hovers over parent item 1 and then chooses child item 6. The big issue here with just the hover state on the parent is that once the hover action shows the child nav, a user will choose the shortest way towards child 6. Meaning, the user won't move the pointer firstly downward, then horizontally to get to child 6. Once the pointer leaves the active area of parent 1 the child nav will immediately disappear. Your UI may not be exposed to that UI flaw but this is the normal case around the web. This is why many many sites have a child nav where the child items are spread out vertically and not horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your "parent" links don't take the user to that parent page. If they do, please refer to [Best way to display a nav item with a single sub-page?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45524/best-way-to-display-a-nav-item-with-a-single-sub-page)

Now if your parent links are only placeholders to open the secondary nav, then you have two options:

1. Update your IA so that it works for both mobile and desktop (all menu items fit into the existing design)
2. Convert the horizontal nav into an off-canvas mobile nav (very common practice in the responsive design). You can see one example on [CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/scottb/pen/javhr) and on [Disney](http://disney.com) websites

**IMPORTANT:** Do not use long clicks and double clicks as those interactions are not commonly understood for the purpose your are trying use them for, especially on the tablet and mobile devices. It will be a very steep learning curve for your users.